# MySQL copy contents of database to another database on the same server

Tags: mysql

I had a production database and a test copy of the database on the same server. Sometimes I want to update the date in the test database to a fresh copy of the production data.

previously I had done this with mysqldump and a pipe it to the test database in bash.

Is there a way to do this directly in MySQL?

Comment: use SQLYog & its synchronization tool

Comment: A paid for tool to replace a one line bash command? I was more interested in the efficiency of a MySQL command over mysqldump and pipes.

Comment: its community addition is free..

Comment: I still think that setting up a GUI tool is more effort than a one line bash command

Comment: mysqldump with pipes isn't at all inefficient, in my opinion. It takes advantage of what Unix does so well - chaining programs together. I don't believe the mysql client alone (the interactive environment) has an ability to do this, because mysqldump _is_ its method. It's part of the same client bundle.

Comment: It still has to convert everything to SQL commands and then re-parse all those statements, no?

Comment: Why don't you use workbench and migration tool it will synchronize the table design as well as can copy the data for you. How many tables do you have? Try a loop and use truncate testdb.table; insert into testdb.table select * from prodctiondb.table

Comment: Because mysqldump and a pipe is way simpler. From all the non answers and long winded suggestions, I am guessing the answer to my question is a "no".